# CloudFlare blocking NVD3 Chart on my website

Tags: cloudflare

I have installed NVD3 Chart on my website today only and now I find that CloudFlare blocks it so the site hangs till continuously.

I am sure that this is an issue with CloudFlare because when I access my website by visiting the direct IP of the server I am able to use everything, but when I visit it via the domain name and hover over the graph, the browser hangs.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it might be an issue with Rocket Loader. Do you have that on? If so, try turning  that off in your performance settings.

Comment: Exactly sir ! I cannot upvote because I am new. This has been fixed by cloudflare though